# Is the twenty fifth or twenty five in the audio?

Tags: listening

Is it the

> This is the six o'clock news for Tuesday the twenty fifth November and first headline.

or

> This is the six o'clock news for Tuesday twenty five November and first headline.

in the audio?
I can't hear clearly.

[the twenty fifth  or twenty five in the audio](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f32t32k4cgd4kbw/output.mp3?dl=0)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for audio interpretation instead of a question about learning English.

Comment: You've been asking several questions about audio, and many of them are either closed or downvoted. I agree with MarcInManhattan in his [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/318612/is-the-twenty-fifth-or-twenty-five-in-the-audio#comment598544_318612) that this is off-topic. I'm also flagging your question for off-topic. Please avoid asking similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very clearly "Tuesday, the twenty fifth of November."

In addition, it would not make sense for the announcer to say "Tuesday, the twenty five of November." The "fifth" form is indicating the twenty fifth day of November.